# Why is this happening to my nested list? (Python)

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, nested-lists

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    records = []
    smallest = 0
    fat = int(input())
    for x in range(fat):
        name = input()
        score = float(input())
        records.append([name, score])
    records.sort(key=lambda x:x[1])
    print(records)
    for i in range(len(records)-3):
        if records[i][1] <= records[i+1][1]:
            del records[i]
        else:
            ''
print(records)
```

When I input this:

```
6
Jorge
3
Mia
3
Gus
5
Myles
4
Gerald
9
Fred
8
```

The output is `[['Mia', 3.0], ['Gus', 5.0], ['Gerald', 9.0]]`. I want to remove all the parts of the list with the lowest value. Why isn't this code working?

Comment: Because you are modifying a list that you are iterating through.  The loop range is set when you enter the loop, but inside the loop you're changing the list.  After you delete item 0, what USED to be item 1 becomes item 0.  To do this, create a new list, and copy over the items you want to keep.

Comment: In your second loop, you're both deleting an entry and moving your pointer(`i`) forward.  This has the effect of skipping records, as you move a new record into where `i` is pointing, then you increase `i` to move past it.  I think you want to increase `i` only if you do not delete an entry.  I don't understand why you need the comparison at all.  You've sorted the list, so won't the comparison always be true?

Answer (score 0):

You have a sorted list of half a dozen records,
with some scores being tied.
Essentially you're doing this:

```
for i in range(3):
    if {i-th score smaller than next score}:
        del records[i]
```

That is very weird.
Why?
First, you are iterating over just half of the records.
But worse, you are mutating the list you're iterating over,
so it's unclear whether a given score will be compared with next score.
Some scores will be compared, and some won't
due to deletion + advancing to next index.
That effectively skips an entry, skips the comparison of a pair of records.

Rather than deleting 2-element records in that way, consider
defining 3-tuples with 3rd element initialized to `False`.
Then set it `True` in the case where you want to delete,
based on a comparison.
Finally, return just those records that still have
a `False` tombstone value.

---

Your `<=` comparsion will *always* be true,
given that it is examining records that have
already been placed into sorted order.

Perhaps you wanted `<` strictly less than, instead?

Answer (score 0):

Since you sort the records, you can just take a slice of the resulting list that is from the 4th entry on, assuming that what you want is to remove the 3 entries with the smallest scores:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    records = [['Jorge', 3], ['Mia', 3], ['Gus', 5], ['Myles', 4], ['Gerald', 9], ['Fred', 8]]

    # records = []
    # fat = int(input())
    # for x in range(fat):
    #     name = input()
    #     score = float(input())
    #     records.append([name, score])

    records.sort(key=lambda x:x[1])

    print(records)

    records = records[3:]

    print(records)
```

Result:

```
[['Jorge', 3], ['Mia', 3], ['Myles', 4], ['Gus', 5], ['Fred', 8], ['Gerald', 9]]
[['Gus', 5], ['Fred', 8], ['Gerald', 9]]
```

I took out your input code in favor of a hard coded value to demonstrate the specific case you give in a reproducible way.  I hate having to enter values to play around with code like this.  You can easily put your input code back in by uncommenting it.

Answer (score -2):

this is because u **cant edit a list in side a loop**, such as del.. so which operations that are all leading to the change in length wont work.. **if the loop is working for a length of list**

for this you can create a temp list and store the required values there.